# How safe is low frequency radiation in I.T. edge cases? (5G, etc)

Tags: cancer, radiation, radiology, bioelectromagnetics, cellular-phone

<sub>***Closely Related:*** [5G Radiation Dangerous?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18410/5g-radiation-dangerous)</sub>

Being inundated with all kinds of 5G health statements, (for & against), I noticed a weird trend - ***the absence of cumulative radiation studies***.

---

## Question:

**What are the health risks of low-frequency radiation, in I.T. edge cases** where there is a far more significant amount of cumulative exposure? - that is, coming from many different sources at once for prolonged periods.

**Case:** I.T. professionals surrounded by 2.5GHz, 5GHz, 40GHz, signals, etc., in addition to 3G, 4G, 5G, etc.  But, the distinction here is that these I.T. professionals are often, (as in the case of Q.A. teams), surrounded by hundreds of these devices at once.

---

## Background:

**According to the NY Times:**

> **[The 5G Health Hazard That Isn’t](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/16/science/5g-cellphones-wireless-cancer.html)** - Human skin blocks the even higher frequencies of sunlight.

**But, the LA Times mentions this:**

> **Is 5G technology dangerous? Early data shows a slight increase of tumors in male rats exposed to cellphone radiation** - The rats were exposed to nine hours of radiation daily, in 10-minutes-on, 10-minutes-off intervals, over their whole bodies for two years. The researchers found increased incidences of rare brain and heart tumors starting at about the federally allowable level of cellphone radiation for brain exposure, with greater incidences at about two and four times those levels.

So, it seems that there is at least some sort of potential for 5G to be dangerous in certain unusual edge cases.

But, what are the radiation health risks for I.T. professionals who are certainly in those edge cases - and much, much, more exposed?

Does being exposed to both high frequency and low frequency, simultaneously, in large quantities, have the potential to increase the risks?

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43134/does-5g-pose-health-risks

Comment: @BryanKrause That's a masterful answer.